# nested loop not working

Tags: python, loops, nested

Can someone tell me why this nested loop only executes the inner while portion once instead of 8 times?

```
corCols = 10
corRows = 8
cCount = 0
for rCount in range(corRows):
    while cCount < corCols:
        print "***" + str(cCount)
        cCount += 1
    print "###" + str(rCount)
```

This prints the first iteration through the columns, then the iterations through the rows but only seems to execute the while portion once?

Comment: It *is* run 10 times, the first time the `for` loop runs.

Comment: Did you mean to ask why it wasn't run 80 times?

Comment: cCount is no longer less than corCols. Btw, Some serious identifier names there.

Answer (score 2):

You need to reset cCount to zero before the inner loop

Answer (score 1):

Your inner loop runs just once, as `cCount` is incremented to `10` the first time the `for` loop iterates. Thereafter `cCount` *stays* at `10` and the `while` condition is always `False`.

If you wanted the `while` loop to run again for each iteration of the `for` loop, reset `cCount` in the `for` loop:

```
corCols = 10
corRows = 8
for rCount in range(corRows):
    cCount = 0
    while cCount < corCols:
        print "***" + str(cCount)
        cCount += 1
    print "###" + str(rCount)
```